# Does LineageOS + microG pass SafetyNet?

Tags: lineageos, micro-g, safety-net

I've recently bought a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 with the intention of installing [the LineageOS + microG](https://lineage.microg.org/) distribution. When reviewing and researching which apps I need to install, I realized that at least one of the apps I need, which is [a two-factor app for my credit card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.entersekt.authapp.sparkasse), requires the phone to be able to pass the (new) Safety Net check that Google added to its Android services.

I'm currently waiting for Xiaomi to finish the countdown allowing me to unlock the bootloader. In the meantime, can anyone tell me whether or not I can use apps requiring Safety Net on that ROM? Infos I found when googling are unclear and contradict each other ([1](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/issues/526), [2](https://www.xda-developers.com/unofficial-lineageos-built-in-microg-avoid-google-services/), [3](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_RemoteDroidGuard/issues/17), [4](https://www.gabsoftware.com/tutorials/how-to-use-microg-on-lineageos-or-cyanogenmod-without-xposed/), [5](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5q0uqj/lineage_os_passes_safetynet_checks/)). I'm not currently planning to root the device or use XPosed or anything similar, and I'm fine with possibly having to relock the bootloader. From what I've seen, the LineageOS + microG distribution includes something called the DroidGuard helper, which emulates or implements the Safety Net features, but it seems to me to depend on the device, the LineageOS version (I'm planning to install 15.1) and patch level, and the whims of Google whether or not the checks pass.

In short, the question I have is:

- On a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4, running LineageOS + microG as offered on the project webpage, will I be able to use an two-factor credit card app like I linked above that requires Safety Net?